Как настроить перелистывание блоков в Wordpress?
Сразу скажу, с cms Wordpress только начал работать и многое не знаю, не налетайте :)
В общем замысел такой, на сайте (Он одностраничный) хочу сделать несколько блоков "Главный", где так скажем приветствие, "Услуги" и "О себе". Реализовать надо так, чтоб каждый блок перелистывался ни как обычная страница, а при прокруте колесика один раз пользователь сразу скролился на второй блок, грубо говоря как вертикальная карусель. Справа по середине было поле с точками, где более яркая точка показывала, на каком блоке сейчас я нахожусь
PS Надеюсь мои мысли хоть кто-то поймет


Ну к WordPress это имеет весьма посредственное отношение, реализовать это можно точно так же как и не на WordPress. В контексте WordPress Вам здесь нужно будет только вывести контент в нужном шаблоне и подключить скрипты/стили в Вашу тему или дочернюю тему.

Найди в репо подходящую тему для одностраничника и будет тебе щастя :)
